# Query Optimization for Correlated Nested Queries (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Is it better or worse for performance to have a WHERE clause in your correlated nested queries or just a WHERE clause in your outer query... ex: The below nested query defines the price_key, but the outer query has references to a price_key and is also defined in the outer queries WHERE statement

```
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT inv.item_key, s.price_key, MAX(inv.last_receive_cost / inv.last_receive_units_case) AS [unit_cost]
            FROM inventory inv
                  INNER JOIN stores s on inv.location_key = s.store_key
            WHERE inv.on_hand_inventory_qty > 0
                  AND inv.last_receive_cost > 0
                  AND inv.last_receive_units_case > 0
                  AND s.price_key = (29)
            GROUP BY inv.item_key, s.price_key
) t ON r.item_key = t.item_key and r.price_key = t.price_key
```

Comment: It is best to filter early

Comment: You could simply put both versions next to each other and look at the resulting query plans. It wouldn't be too surprising if it turns out that the query optimizer uses the same query-plan for both versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT inv.item_key --, s.price_key
                 , MAX(inv.last_receive_cost / inv.last_receive_units_case) AS [unit_cost]
            FROM inventory inv
                  INNER JOIN stores s on inv.location_key = s.store_key
            WHERE inv.on_hand_inventory_qty > 0
                  AND inv.last_receive_cost > 0
                  AND inv.last_receive_units_case > 0
                  AND s.price_key = 29
            GROUP BY inv.item_key 
-- , s.price_key
) t   ON r.item_key = t.item_key 
     and r.price_key = 29
```

Comment: I agree that filtering prior to the grouping is important, and that grouping on something that is already filtered can cause a silly redundant performance problem so it should be removed if possible.